# How do I get rid of a whole row of NULL when I'm using a UNION?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Select * from OPENQUERY (PORTAL,
''SELECT st.last AS "Last Name", st.first AS "First Name", ct.DeviceName, SUM
         (ct.PageCount) AS "Count", pm.TotalPerPage
FROM printer_stats.Counts ct 
INNER JOIN dv.staff st on st.id = ct.UserID
LEFT JOIN network_map.PrintersToDevices ptd ON ptd.DeviceID = ct.DeviceID
LEFT JOIN network_map.PrinterModels pm ON ptd.PrinterID = pm.PrinterID
WHERE ct.UserID = "'+@UserID+'" and ct.PageCount > 0 and ct.Date >= "'+@AcademicYTD+'"
UNION
 SELECT stu.last_name AS "Last Namae", stu.first_name AS "First Name", 
ct.DeviceName,SUM(ct.PageCount) AS "Count", pm.TotalPerPage 
FROM printer_stats.Counts ct
INNER JOIN dv.student stu on stu.username = ct.Username
LEFT JOIN network_map.PrintersToDevices ptd ON ptd.DeviceID = ct.DeviceID
LEFT JOIN network_map.PrinterModels pm ON ptd.PrinterID = pm.PrinterID
WHERE ct.UserID = "'+@UserID+'" and ct.PageCount > 0 and ct.Date  
>= "'+@AcademicYTD+'" 
GROUP BY ct.DeviceName 
ORDER BY 4 DESC'')
```

I get results like this:

```
 Last Name  First Name DeviceName       Count TotalPerPage
 Stewart    Jesse      BG-LMC-HP4100-01 39    0.0287581
 Stewart    Jesse      BG-LMC-HP4100-02 9     0.0287581
 Stewart    Jesse      BG-903-RI4210    2     0.013341
 Stewart    Jesse      BG-218-HP4000    1     0.013341
 NULL       NULL       NULL             NULL  NULL
```

I don't want the last row of all NULLS.

I know they are coming from the first `SELECT` for Staff since there should be no matching rows: The user is a Student, so there wouldn't be a match.

I need to know how to only show rows with data in all fields.

Comment: Does the SELECT for staff also return nulls when run alone - without the other part of the union?

Comment: No both parts run perfectly when ran alone. Only when I UNION them do I get the row of NULLs and only when it is a Student UserType. A Staff UserType doesn't return the row of NULLs.

Comment: Are any of your questions really for SQL Server? If they all go to a MySql server through the OpenQuery, you are more or less wasting people's time, since they (or I, at least) try to answer your question from a SQL Server angle (and syntax).

Answer (score 1):

If you know what part of your `UNION` is providing the Null-row, you should first look at it, ensure that it returns what you want and fix your problem there.

However, if you're otherwise satisfied that the query is as it should be, you can always do a hack with an `EXCEPT SELECT NULL`-construction: (I've included surrounding lines for reference)

```
...
WHERE ct.UserID = "'+@UserID+'" and ct.PageCount > 0 and ct.Date   >= "'+@AcademicYTD+'" 
EXCEPT
SELECT NULL AS "Last Name", NULL AS "First Name", NULL as DeviceName, NULL AS "Count",  NULL AS TotalPerPage
GROUP BY ct.DeviceName
ORDER BY 4 DESC'')
```

Comment: I get an Error stating Check manual for syntax to use near 'EXCEPT 
SELECT NULL AS "Last Name", NULL AS "First Name", NULL as DeviceName, N' at line 14".

Comment: I'm not going to debug syntax errors for you. But, the right parenthesis after the GROUP BY might be a good place to start. Given that I don't have your system, I haven't run your full SQl, but recreated a simple version that works on my system.

Comment: the right parenthesis after the GROUP BY ??? Do you mean the parens after the ORDER BY 4 DESC'')....   Sorry I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Anders UP -  Is the above example you wrote not the correct syntax?

Comment: I wrote fairly close to the correct syntax - but copy'n'pasting your original example doesn't parse to begin with for me. If I remove the OpenQuery-part and the '', the example parses both with and without my addition. This indicates that your problem is elsewhere. Looking at your errormessages given to me and to @rdkleine below, I'd guess your OpenQuery goes to fetch from a MySQL-base. If that is the case, you've tagged your question incorrectly - and obviously the example doesn't work, since MySQL doesn't have the EXCEPT-keyword (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
WHERE NOT [Last Name] IS NULL
```

Comment: after using this syntax on all fields I get and error "Invalid use of group function" Syntax used: WHERE NOT(st.last) IS NULL and NOT(st.first) IS NULL and NOT(ct.DeviceName) IS NULL and NOT(SUM(ct.PageCount)) and NOT(pm.TotalPerPage) IS NULL and rest of original WHERE